# CSS Child selector - manipulating same div class within two different divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, parent-child

My aim is to control the position and margin attributes via css of my div class element "textwidget" which appears on different positions within my site.

This is my structure:

```
<header class="site-header">
<hgroup class="full-container">

<div id="header-sidebar" >
    <aside id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">          
        <div class="textwidget">    ...     </div>
    </aside>

</div>

</hgroup>
</header>


<footer class="site-footer">

<div id="footer-widgets" class="full-container">
    <aside id="text-5" class="widget widget_text">
        <div class="textwidget">     ....      </div>
    </aside>
</div>

</footer>
```

And this is, what i tried in CSS, but what didn't worked out:

```
.textwidget{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
margin-top: 30px;
text-align: right;
}

footer > .textwidget{
position: absolute !important;
left: 0 !important;
text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: `>` means select direct child, `.textwidget` is not direct to `footer` element

Comment: For reference, the hgroup element has been removed from the HTML5 specification and should no longer be used. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hgroup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
footer > .textwidget{
```

targets only elements of class 'textwidget' that are *direct descendents* of footer, ie:

```
<footer class="site-footer">
    <div class="textwidget">
        This div will be targeted
    </div>
</footer>
```

Remove the > and it will target *any* elements of class 'textwidget' within the footer.

Selector you want: **footer .textwidget**

---

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: Don't use W3Schools as a reference, here is why... http://www.w3fools.com/ use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ instead :)

Answer (score 2):

`.textwidget` is the great-grandchild of the `footer`, not the child.

Use a descendant combinator (a space) instead of a child combinator (a greater than sign).

```
footer .textwidget {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

You can get rid of the `!important`s too. They are a horrible sledgehammer at the best of times, and aren't needed here before `footer .textwidget` is more specific than `.textwidget`.

Comment: Thx Quentin! Works perfect! Love your films, too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

in the example you gave the div with a class of `.textwidget` is not a direct child of the `footer` try:

```
footer aside > .textwidget{
position: absolute !important;
left: 0 !important;
text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey Paulie_D, thanks! Tried it and it worked as well!